# Android: Long running file recording thread slows UI

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm creating an application which will receive sensor data from multiple devices and needs to be able to record it. I created my own custom Thread which will open, record, and close files at the request of my UI thread. However, it appears to be slowing my UI while recording. Could this be due to the overhead of each message? Is there a better way to do a long task like this?

```
public class FileThread extends Thread {

public static final int MSG_OPEN_FILE = 1000,
                        MSG_WRITE_FILE = 2000,
                        MSG_CLOSE_FILE = 3000;

public Handler handler;
private OutputStream fileStream;

@Override
public void run() {
    Looper.prepare();

    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch(msg.what) {
                case MSG_OPEN_FILE: {
                    final String fileName = (String)msg.obj;
                    final File aclSensorDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "ACLSensor");

                    if(!aclSensorDirectory.exists()) {
                        if(!aclSensorDirectory.mkdir()) {
                            Log.e("FileThread", "Couldn't make directory!");
                        }
                    }

                    final File file = new File(aclSensorDirectory, fileName);

                    try {
                        fileStream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    break;
                }
                case MSG_WRITE_FILE: {
                    final String data = (String)msg.obj;
                    try {
                        fileStream.write(data.getBytes());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case MSG_CLOSE_FILE: {
                    try {
                        fileStream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Looper.loop();
}
```

}

Comment: Use Traceview and figure out where your problem really lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a thread running all the time, I think it is better for you to use AsyncTask and triggers the task for each message.

There is no point to keep a long running thread that is probably idle most of the time.

Comment: So I would open the file on the main UI thread and then for each chunk of data dispatch an asynctask to do the individual write?